# Не работает click, если элемент добавлен через appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('<a id="others" class="type">другое (' + others + ')</a>').appendTo("#type");

$('a').click(function () {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    var typeResult = $(this).attr("id");

    $("a.type").css({
        "border": "1px black solid"
    });

    $(this).css({
        "border": "1px red solid"
    });
});
```

Не работает, если элемент добавлен через `appendTo`. Если элемент просто на странице ввести, то все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('<a id="others" class="type">другое (' + 1 + ')</a>').
  appendTo("#type").
  click(function () { 
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    var typeResult = $(this).attr("id");
    $("a.type").css({
        "border":"1px black solid"
    });
    $(this).css({
        "border":"1px red solid"
    });
  });
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSbEC/)

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
А как зделать чтобы кликало после загурзки страницы?

Comment: Легко. =)

    $(function(){
     $('[...]').click(function(){
      [...]
     }).click();
    });

Answer (score 4):

В jQuery есть хорошая функция привязки обработчика к событию (см [live( тип, функция )](http://jquery-docs.ru/Events/live/#source))

Возможно испльзование именно ее облегчит вам код

Comment: Именно live наше все)
    $('a').live('click',function () {
        ...
    });

Comment: начиная с версии 1.7.1 всё-таки on(), а live() считается устаревшим.

Comment: @Syabrowka, ложь похоже.